# Android getevent and sendevent : How to execute recorded events from Windows command window?

Tags: android, batch-file, user-interface, adb

I have recorded the events that are triggered when I play around with a UI on Android 4.4.2

This is the command I execute from a Windows command prompt:

```
adb shell getevent > capturedevents.txt
```

I then run the .txt file through a "parser" which produces a bat file :

```
modifiedeventfile.bat
```

When I try to execute the bat file from a Windows command prompt nothing happens on the phone and if I run:

```
adb shell getevent > response.txt
```

while I'm executing the bat file, I only get this:

```
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0035 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0036 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0001 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000

/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
```

The response indicates that the phone is only responding to the first 2 "commands" (where a 'command' is terminated by 0 0 0)

What am I doing wrong?

I would like to be able to capture/record events on the phone and "play" them back by executing a bat file.

Here are some links to download the files I'm referring to:

http://www.filedropper.com/capturedevents
http://www.filedropper.com/modifiedeventfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links are empty so I cannot verify your approach.

Do you send recorded events via adb? Ex. `adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1: 0003 0035 00000000` If not, change parser to add string `adb shell sendevent` in front of each line in **capturedevents.txt** and then send them via adb.

btw. Sometimes, you will need to add small delay via ping. Ex. `ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul`

EDIT:

```
:: open keaypad
adb shell input keyevent 5
adb shell input tap 120 150
:: press the button 'DEL'
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0003 57 48
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0001 330 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0003 53 870
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0003 54 1785
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0003 48 6
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0003 49 6
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0003 50 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0003 60 4294967206
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0000 0000 0
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
:: release the button
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0003 57 4294967295
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0001 330 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0000 0 0
```

It was recorded on Samsung Galaxy S4

Comment: Yes, I send the events via adb. Can you post an example of the following: 1) Navigate to some (X,Y) coordinate on screen where there's a UI button 2) Issue press button down 3) Hold button down for 1 second 4) Release button

Comment: One last question: How do you execute the sequence of adb shell commands? Do you execute one command at a time from an adb shell? Or do you transfer a file containing all the commands to the SDCARD and then execute the file? If so, how? And how do you record the events (and parse the recorded data) ?

Comment: The code above is fully functional batch script. I send one command after another to the android device (i run batch script on my PC). The most important part is a delay (ping) to emulate press time. I manually parsed the recorded data (you have to figure out how to do parsing script). The getevent output is different for different devices (Galaxy S3, S4, Note3, etc.). 1st, define which Event represents touchscreen. 2nd, which messages represent taps/press/xy (try to google it).

Comment: Do I need to change it from event1 to event3? I have followed the steps and captured a swipe event but not able to make it work..